# Powershell replace in file multiple times

Tags: regex, powershell

I got following line like 8-9 times in one config file.

```
ProxyPass http://servername.de.domain:randomport/randomword
```

I built the following regex:

```
(?:ProxyPass)[[:blank:]](?=http)(.*)(?=:)
```

The part I want to edit is servername and domain... I get the match with my regex but i am not getting the powershell command to work. I tought about:

```
(Get-Content $file) -replace $regexProxyPass1, "    ProxyPass http://$serverName.$domain" | Set-Content $file
```

Comment: .NET regex does not support POSIX character classes. `[[:blank:]]` would not work. Use `\s` instead.

Comment: Looks like you can simplify your regex into `ProxyPass\shttp:[^:]*` Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/s5R2AG/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET regex does not support POSIX character classes. `[[:blank:]]` should be replaced with `\s`.

See the full regex replace snippet:

```
PS> $domain = 'mydomain'
PS> $serverName = 'myservername'
PS> $s = 'ProxyPass http://servername.de.domain:randomport/randomword'
PS> $s -replace '(ProxyPass\s+http://)[^:]+', "`$1$serverName.$domain"
ProxyPass http://myservername.mydomain:randomport/randomword
```

**Details**

- `(ProxyPass\s+http://)` - Group 1: `ProxyPass`, 1+ whitespaces, `http://`
- `[^:]+` - 1 or more chars other than `:`

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28ProxyPass%5cs%2bhttp%3a%2f%2f%29%5b%5e%3a%5d%2b&i=ProxyPass+http%3a%2f%2fservername.de.domain%3arandomport%2frandomword&r=%241myserverName.mydomain).

The `$1` in the replacement pattern stands for the value captured into Group 1. Mind the escape - `` `$1 `` - that is necessary here as the double quoted literals may contain extrapolated variables.